# Enabling UTF-8 file encoding in various text editors

Tags: unicode, accents, input-encodings, ide

Many IDE / text editors used by latex community do not encode tex files into utf-8 by default. When trying to use diacritics, various issues may arise.

Example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
Denis Bogdănaş
\end{document}
```

Let's create a new tex file (my OS is Windows) and open it in TeXnicCenter. Copy-pasting the code above to TeXnicCenter will look like this:

[image: screenshot txc]

However, in the compiled document diacritics are rendered as question marks (?):

[image: screenshot rendered txc]

Closing and reopening the file exposes the issue:

[image: screenshot txc open 2]

There are problems with UTF-8 in other text editors as well. How can we check if our file is correctly encoded, and how to enable UTF-8 in popular TeX IDEs?

Comment: It works for me using TeX Live 2014 on Linux. Maybe you have to install some other fonts.

Comment: I'm using windows, miktex. Could you specify what have to be installed?

Comment: Use the Package manager to install some package related with extra fonts. You can search for cm-super, maybe. Or some fonts.

Comment: Also, is your `tex` file UTF or ISO encoded?

Comment: I already have cm-super.

Comment: How can I find out file encoding?

Comment: What editor are you using? TeXmaker? If yes, you can see in the status bar.

Comment: Maybe it is related to your system. When I copy from your post and paste *Denis Bogdănaş* into TeXstudio (UTF encoded file) and compile, it works. After, I close the `tex` file and open again, it recognize the characters and compile normally.

Comment: Compiling the file, do you see the expected output? It might be, that the editor and its font aren't able to show the glyphs.

Comment: most likely your file is not UTF-8 encoded, we can't tell as the text is always utf-8 encoded once pasted into this website.

Comment: @Sigur UTF-8 is an ISO format as well:-) (ISO 10646)

Comment: Thank you all for answers. I extended the scope of this questions and added all my test results so far. Hope it will be useful for others.

Comment: Your question seems to imply that the file has to be encoded in UTF-8 in order to use diacritics, that is not of course the case, you can save in latin1, or even ascii, so long as you declare the encoding you use to inputenc.

Comment: That was an assumption in the initial question, right. Still, UTF-8 would be the preferred choice. I don't want to think what problems one might have using a less popular encoding.

Comment: why do you think there would be problems, latex was used for some decades before utf8 support was added (utf8 decoding using some of my code as it happens) an encoding such as latin1 is _much_ easier for pdflatex to deal with than utf8.

Comment: One possible scenario: after adding a few more references, nicely formatted in UTF, copy-pasted from an internet database, I might discover that the author is no longer rendered properly, because the diacritics in his name are not supported by latin-1, or encoded differently than in utf. Just guessing.

Answer (score 1):

TeXnicCenter: File should be saved for the first time through save as dialog:

File -> Save As -> Encoding checkbox: select UTF-8:

[image: scs txc 3]

Now it should compile properly:

[image: result]

The scenario described in the question seems to be a TeXnicCenter bug. (version 2.02)

Answer (score 0):

TeXstudio: no issues are present. UTF seems to be enabled by default.

[image: TexStudio]

The file encoding is displayed in the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

**Notepad++**: Default encoding for empty files seems to be ANSI, displayed in the status bar:

[image]

The wrong result is easily visible. Diacritics are converted to regular latin characters.

Encoding should be changed to UTF-8 without BOM:

[image: UTF-8 without BOM]

After copy-pasting again the same text, it is displayed properly:

[image: notepad++ ok]

Comment: The "wrong result" could equally seem to  be a latex error in that you have used `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` instead of declaring the encoding used, `\usepackage[cp1252]{inputenc}`

Comment: Nope, simple copy-paste into a new file erases diacritics. NPP has no way to know what `inputenc` means.

Comment: Yes. The editor does not need to know anything about `inputenc` it is the responsibility of the latex author to use `inputenc` to tell latex what encoding the file is using, which is visibly **not** utf8 in the screenshot here.

Comment: The main point of this thread is actually unrelated to inputenc and latex per se. Simple copy-paste + save of text using many latex editors leads to information loss. Solutions to prevent this.

Comment: If you are saying that editors only work with UTF-8 text then that is clearly false in general or you have some very poor editor configurations, but that is off topic for this site. It's probably a good idea to move towards UTF-8 for any new documents but in any reasonable editor its default encoding should work. That is if the diacritics show _in the editor_ they will work in latex, so long as you specify the encoding that is actually used.

Comment: I agree. Only TeXniccenter behavior is a clear bug, worth having documented on the net. You see the characters with diacritics in the editor, there are no unsaved changes, compilation result is wrong, yet only when you reopen the file you see discrepancies. But the problem is worth addressing more thoroughly, IMHO. There were a couple of questions on this site both specific to texniccenter and to all IDEs in general, related to UTF.