# Use latin1 and utf8 at the same time

Tags: texstudio, input-encodings, include

In the same article, I am including several section by the function `\include{}`, but they are encoding with latin1 and utf8. I was using `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}`, but when I try to include (ejercicio4), a file coded in utf8, it doesn't work. If I try to change by `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` the other sections fails.

I tried with [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357809/using-inputs-both-in-utf8-and-latin1), but I couldn't make it work.

Here I show a sample:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[activeacute,spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm,amscd}

\begin{document}

    \include{ejercicio4}

\end{document}
```

- How could I fix it?

Comment: it is possible to switch encodings (but the shared aux file makes things a bit tricky) but there is no good reason to have the files in latin-1 , why not just save them all as UTF-8?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It would be better for me from latin-1 to UTF-8, but I don't know how I can save it with other coding.

Comment: almost any editor these days should let you save the file in UTF-8 but that is purely a question about the editor menus nothing directly to do with latex, but you have not said what editor you use.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I use TeXstudio.

Comment: there are plenty of texstudio users here someone will tell you how to save in utf8 (I don't have that editor so can't easily answer:-)

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/244260/1090